# PrimeNG datatable Angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a JSON where there is array inside array and want to filter its property.  Below is my JSON object :

```
{
  "Id":1,
  "Name" :divya,
  "USer":{
    "AssigneeID":1
  }
}
```

and I want to filter it based on property `AssigneeId`.

Comment: Exactly, please share your recent code.

Comment: <p-column field="Users" sortable="true">
        <template pTemplate="header" let-col>
          <div class="search-box-container w-90-p">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Assignee" #userlist (keyup)="filterUserlist($event.target.value)" />
            <i class="img-sprite search-icon-sm"></i>
          </div>
        </template>


        <template pTemplate="body" #col let-users="rowData">


          <span>{{formatUsers(users)  }}</span>
        </template>

Comment: I have written custom filter but that is not getting synchronise with othe filters.